# npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Got the following error while executing `ng new project-name` in angular project

> npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
>   npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...:"~0.0.0","webpack-de'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abhi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-13T10_24_02_151Z-debug.log
>   Package install failed, see above.

**What I have tried :**
1. npm cache clean --force
2. npm cache verify
3. npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...5.0","rimraf":"^2.2.8'

**Current Versions:**
Node : 10.14.2
NPM : 6.5.0
OS : Windows

Comment: have try this `npm uninstall -g angular-cli npm cache clean` after that `npm install -g angular-cli` after that try

Comment: @Abhishek Getting same error while installing angular-cli

Comment: Post your `package.json` file

Comment: @PatrickHollweck I am new to Angular.Can you please tell me where can find that file?

Answer (score 15):

You do not need to uninstall or install anything. Just

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then

```
npm install
```

will do.

Comment: What's the difference from other existing answers?

Comment: You do not need to uninstall or install anything just `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install` will do

Answer (score 4):

In the folder where you have tried to create project setup, just run these 2 commands:

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm install`

Afterwards, run the commands needed to setup your project directory.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was solved by going to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache and deleting its contents manually , then later running **cmd as Administrator** and running `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

open the **cmd** in **adminstator mode** then run the following commands in order specify

```
npm cache clean --force 
go in the c:/user/user_name/AppData/Roaming/npm     => clean this folder 
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new project_name
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete node_modules folder
delete package-lock.json 
npm clear cache -f
npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete package-lock.json and try installing again.