# I cannot install nodemon without getting an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I am new to npm installation. I recently tried installing nodemon in npm by using `$ npm install nodemon`. I couldn't install it and got an error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ndencies":{},"devDepe'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\samya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-10T11_24_26_427Z-debug.log
```

I tried reading the log of this run but couldn't really understand it. Please tell me where I am going wrong and please guide me. Thank You!

Comment: Try with installing older versions. Also check your package.json file for syntax errors.

Comment: can you show us your package.json

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759929/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try running this it helped me

```
npm cache clean --force
```