# Error while installing Firebase using npm

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I'm trying to install firebase using npm command. I tried different commands but still getting this same error.

> ```
> npm install --save firebase
> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0ae6e1d9734f431ca8c39'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/ven/.npm/_logs/2020-07-20T14_28_15_516Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759929/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```